# Оформление БД. Как сохранять экземпляры баз данных?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Т.е. я прописал код для базы данных:

```
public class DBHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recordsDB";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_1 = "results_1";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_2 = "results_2";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_3 = "results_3";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_4 = "results_4";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_5 = "results_5";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_6 = "results_6";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_7 = "results_7";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_8 = "results_8";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_9 = "results_9";
public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_10 = "results_10";
//public static final String TABLE_RESULTS_OVERALL = "overall";

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_1 = "one";
public static final String KEY_2 = "two";
public static final String KEY_3 = "three";
public static final String KEY_4 = "four";
public static final String KEY_5 = "five";
public static final String KEY_6 = "six";
public static final String KEY_7 = "seven";
public static final String KEY_8 = "eight";
public static final String KEY_9 = "nine";
public static final String KEY_10 = "ten";
public static final String KEY_11 = "eleven";
public static final String KEY_12 = "twelve";
public static final String KEY_13 = "thirteen";
public static final String KEY_14 = "fourteen";
public static final String KEY_15 = "fifteen";
public static final String KEY_16 = "sixteen";
public static final String KEY_17 = "seventeen";
public static final String KEY_18 = "eighteen";
public static final String KEY_19 = "nineteen";
public static final String KEY_20 = "twenty";
public static final String KEY_21 = "twenty_one";
public static final String KEY_22 = "twenty_two";
public static final String KEY_23 = "twenty_three";
public static final String KEY_24 = "twenty_four";
public static final String KEY_25 = "twenty_five";
public static final String KEY_26 = "twenty_six";
public static final String KEY_27 = "twenty_seven";
public static final String KEY_28 = "twenty_eight";
public static final String KEY_29 = "twenty_nine";
public static final String KEY_30 = "thirty";
public static final String KEY_31 = "thirty_one";
public static final String KEY_32 = "thirty_two";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_RESULTS_1 + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key," + KEY_1 + " int," + KEY_2 + " int," + KEY_3 + " int," + KEY_4 + " int," + KEY_5
            + " int," + KEY_6 + " int," + KEY_7 + " int,"+ KEY_8 + " int," + KEY_9 + " int," + KEY_10 +
            " int," + KEY_11 + " int," + KEY_12 + " int,"+ KEY_13 + " int," + KEY_14 + " int," + KEY_15 +
            " int," + KEY_16 + " int," + KEY_17 + " int,"+ KEY_18 + " int," + KEY_19 + " int," + KEY_20 +
            " int," + KEY_21 + " int," + KEY_22 + " int,"+ KEY_23 + " int," + KEY_24 + " int," + KEY_25 +
            " int," + KEY_26 + " int," + KEY_27 + " int,"+ KEY_28 + " int," + KEY_29 + " int," + KEY_30 +
            " int," + KEY_31 + " int," + KEY_32 + " int" + ")");

   // db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_RESULTS_OVERALL + "(" + KEY_ID
           // + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_TIME + " float" + ")");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_RESULTS_1);
   // db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_RESULTS_OVERALL);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Все результаты будут храниться в ней, что логично, однако эти результаты снимаются с разных участков, и мне нужно, чтобы при вызове базы данных прогружались не все результаты, а только результаты с одного участка.

Comment: Если уж начали говорить о базах данных, то давайте говорить терминами баз данных. Что такое участок по вашему и что значит "разные участки", "все участки", "один участок"? Пока я вижу только таблицы однотипные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под участком, и собственно сам вопрос. Но если правильно понял, вы ищете это:

```
public Cursor getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{"key1"};
    Cursor cursor = database.query("results_1", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

выбирайте нужную таблицу и делайте выборку из необходимых столбцов, или же отображайте все столбцы.

```
public Cursor getData() {
    Cursor cursor = database.query("results_1", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

> Cursor cursor = database.query(String table, String[] columns, String
>   selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
>   String orderBy);